# Configure ASP.NETCore Identity with Identity Server 4.1

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I want to use ASP NET Identity (Core 3.1) with IdentityServer4. I am trying to store, users credentials in AspNet... tables and use Identity server for access control. I tried the ASPNetIdentity and EntityFramework examples and managed to create one project with both samples(IDP-app). I also created a .NET Core MVC project with authentication enabled(let’s call it (MVC-app). My intention is

1. User will request for MVC-app, and the system will redirect to IDP-app for authentication. It successfully authenticates.
2. Now the (MVC-app) application should show the “Hello [UserName]” and should be able to pass the authenticated user information to other controllers and pages.

Here step 1 works perfectly OK, but while redirecting to (MVC-app), it’s getting into a continuous loop

So you, please help me with the following.

1. Use ASP Identity functions like (create user, manage user, etc.) as provided in the ASP Net Identity template and use IdentityServer4 for authentication and claims.
2. Once authenticated in the IDP-app, how can I pass the authenticated user information to my MVC app for authentication and authorization.

Can someone help me with this, please?

If you feel I am not following some best practice here, please suggest the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read his tutorial article:[ASP.NET Core Identity Series – OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect & IdentityServer](https://chsakell.com/2019/03/11/asp-net-core-identity-series-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-identityserver/),

i think you can get anything you need.
I also deploy a auth server in my country(China) [My own Auth Server](http://authserver.poetrysharing.com/),
so it maybe visit slowly in your there,

you can use it directly to test authorize your website, spa or app etc.

Just add the client you want.